# For every Lebesgue measure set $E,$ the map $x\mapsto\overline{\lambda}(E\cap(E+x))$ is continuous

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm trying to prove the next:

For every Lebesgue measure set $E,$ the map $x\mapsto\overline{\lambda}(E\cap(E+x))$ is continuous.

Here $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{A}_{\mathbb{R}}^{*},\overline{\lambda})$ is the complete Lebesgue measure space over real numbers.

To prove this is suggested to use Monotone Class Theorem. So I'm proving the class $\mathcal{M}$ defined by $$\mathcal{M}=\{E\in\mathcal{A}_{\mathbb{R}}^{*}:x\mapsto\overline{\lambda}(E\cap(E+x))\space\text{is continuous}\}$$ is a monotone class.

I've proved such class is a monotone class and contains the algebra $\mathcal{A}$ of finite disjoint unions of elements $(-\infty,a],(b,c],(d,\infty).$ Then, by Monotone Class Theorem $\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}\subset\mathcal{M},$ i.e., $\mathcal{M}$ contains Borelian sets, but at this point I don't know how to proceed to have the entire Lebesgue $\sigma-$algebra.

Any kind of help is thanked in advanced.

Comment: Does $E$ have finite measure?

Comment: Not necessarily. Is there a problem without such hypothesis?

Comment: How did you prove that $\mathcal M$ is a monotone class? Pointwise limits of continuous functions need not be continuous.

Comment: I see what you say. I don't consider it. Thanks for the observation. Is there a suggestion to fix this?

Comment: No, I don't think you can use Monotone lass Theorem at all to prove this. When $E$ has finite measure you can approximate it by finite disjoint unions of intervals of the type $[a,b)$ with $-\infty <a <b <\infty$ from which the result follows easily.

Comment: I began proving it with intervals of the form $(a,b],$ but I have problems proving the proposition for disjoint union of such intervals and the general case, so I opted to use monotone class theorem as a hint of a book.

Comment: @Suiz96, what book was this? Thanks.

Comment: @Lotte  The book is "A Course on Borel Sets".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** We can write every Lebesgue measureable set as the union of a Borel measurable set and a null set. Clearly every null set is in $\mathcal{M}$ (as the zero function is continuous).

Comment: That was so clever! Thanks.

Comment: Why is the function continuous when $E$ is  a Borel set?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks for pointing out. It was already late and I did not check the OPs reasoning for the Borel case. For infinite measure it is simply wrong. As we can take $E= \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} [3n, 3n+1]$, then $x \mapsto \overline{\lambda} (E \cap (E+x))$ drops from infinity to $0$ at $x=1$. Let me fix my answer after work.